# Poisson distribution application example

Tags: probability, probability-theory, poisson-distribution

There's this example in a book I'm reading, and I don't understand the solution — how exactly to calculate the probability  $P(X ≥ 12) $

> Example: During the last few years in Gotham City, a provincial city with
>   more than 100,000 inhabitants, there have been eight serious fires per year,
>   on average. Last year, by contrast, twelve serious fires blazed. How exceptional is that?
>
> Solution: To answer this question, you calculate the probability of twelve or more fires
>   and not the probability of exactly twelve fires. The desired probability is given
>   by
>   $P(X ≥ 12) = 0.112$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It got to me.

$P(X=k)=e^{-x}\frac{x^k}{k!}$

**Since all probabilities(constant $x$ and variable $k$) sum up to $1$**, we can find $P(X≥12)$ by extracting from $1$ all probabilities $P(X)$ excluding those with $X≥12$

$$1 - P(X<12) = 1 - \sum_{i=0}^{11}P(i)$$

Or I could just calculate probabilities from $12$ up to $x^2$
$$P(X≥12) = \sum_{i=12}^{x^2}P(i)$$

And one thing I did not see clearly is that in the example $x=8$ because $x=np$ which is the average, so is the $8$ in the example

Comment: Why $x^2$ here, this looks very weird? Also you should specify that $k=12$ in your last sum

Comment: @Winther just seem like an acceptable number in terms of until what number to keep summing to get a good approximation

Comment: You are adding an estimate that might work for this specific cases, but not in general, without even pointing this out. For example if $x=2$ then summing up to $x^2=4$ would not be enough. The sum formally is to infinity and that is what should be said. Then you might point out that numerically you only need to sum up some finite number and in this case something like $20$ is more than enough.

Comment: @Winther that is true. I guess I let myself wave my hands a bit because I've been answering to myself, but in reality this answer for everyone but me. Forgot... Thanks a lot for pointing out :)

Answer (score 1):

100000 is Irelavent

$X\sim$ $Po(8)$

$P(X\geq12)=1-P(X\leq 11)=1-0.8881=0.1119$

Comment: How do I calculate P(X ≤ 11)?

Comment: using probability tables (most likely at the end of the book)

Comment: are you taking an exam?

Comment: no, I'm not. I just want to know what calculations I need to perform so I can implement it in a programming language

Comment: did you find the probability table?

Comment: Hi if you are coding this you might as well implement your own probability table. You have the rate parameter $8$ as per the answer, presumably you know the Poisson mass function, so you just need to calculate $\sum_{k=0}^N \frac {\lambda ^n \cdot e^{- \lambda}}{n!}$ for appropriate $\lambda$ and $N$ in code.

Comment: If you have Excel on your computer, the POISSON worksheet function will calculate $P(X \le 11)$.